# Angularjs: Controller Register Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am newbie of angularJS follwing this tutorial [AngularJS Fundamentals In 60-ish Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM) on youtube, I've written same code as this guy does everything is working fine till adding the controller. Whenever i add controller i get this error.

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'SimpleController' is not registered.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>First page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'Ali', city: 'lahore' },
                { name: 'Ahsan', city: "lahore" }
            ];
        }
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <div >
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            Name: <input data-ng-model="name" type="text" name="customerName" />

            <div id="print">{{ name }}</div>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name+'-'+cust.city}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's your version of angularjs?

Comment: license AngularJS v1.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the controller **`SimpleController`** with the module.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("SimpleController", function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'Ali', city: 'lahore' },
                { name: 'Ahsan', city: "lahore" }
            ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            Name: <input data-ng-model="name" type="text" name="customerName" />
            <div id="print">{{ name }}</div>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name+'-'+cust.city}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed version of your code.

You need to name a `ng-app` and attach a controller to that `app` like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>First page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        var App = angular.module('app', []);
        App.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope){
          $scope.customers = [
            { name: 'Ali', city: 'lahore' },
            { name: 'Ahsan', city: "lahore" }
          ];
        }]);
    </script>
</head>


<body>
<div >
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name: <input data-ng-model="name" type="text" name="customerName" />

        <div id="print">{{ name }}</div>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name+'-'+cust.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess the guy in the video is using angularjs1.2-, you can install the specified version by `npm install angular@1.2.x`.

```js
function SimpleController($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [{
      name: 'Ali',
      city: 'lahore'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ahsan',
      city: "lahore"
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">

<head>
  <title>First page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
  <div>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name: <input data-ng-model="name" type="text" name="customerName" />

      <div id="print">{{ name }}</div>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name+'-'+cust.city}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the way to define a controller have changed since angularjs1.3.0, changelog **[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3)**.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("SimpleController", function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [{
      name: 'Ali',
      city: 'lahore'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ahsan',
      city: "lahore"
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>First page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
  <div>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name: <input data-ng-model="name" type="text" name="customerName" />

      <div id="print">{{ name }}</div>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name+'-'+cust.city}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```